# By publishing this workflow, conditions and actions inside imprsonation stesp will run using your credentials.

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have a workflow in a sharepoint document library, i am doing some maintenance of it. I am using SP designer 2010.
I have done some wording changes in one of the email of the workflow. it has impersonation steps.  it has been used to remove all permissions and provide contribute access to relevant people. the live document library has live data.
so after doing the changes i save the workflow. but when i wanted to publish it gives that error message , which i have used to create a new workflow , but not used in maintenance. "By publishing this workflow, conditions and actions inside Impersonation steps will run using your credentials. only continue this if this is the intended behavior".
i am not sure what to click, should i click "OK". i have full permission on the site. but the users on  the impersonation will have only contribute access...
please suggest. kindly in-touch with me if need any clarification.